# Can a line stretch vertically in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have that contains some text entered dynamically by the user from a web front end. This sections of the report is allow to grow according its contents. This section is divided by line to create a table-like layout. However, when the content so that makes the section grow the line does't stretch vertically. Is it possible to make the line strecth?

An image is better than words.

[image]

Comment: Is using the border property of the cell or textbox an option? That can be set per side.

Comment: Nice. That worked like a charm. I was using a line object. I already got rid of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the border property of a cell or textbox. It can be set separately for each side: both color and thickness have a default property for all sides, then each individual side's settings override that when set.